# WPF Load svg resource as combobox image

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg, combobox

I have created a usercontrol combobox that loads images with a description. Because I'm reusing the images in different sizes I would like to use a vector image. That I have accomplished. I can load the vector image, resize it etc.

What I also want is to populate a combobox with these images as part of the datasource. I can load the svg as a dynamic resource but then I have the same image for every item in the combobox. This is of course not what I want. Below is the part of the xaml that I use for creating the image and description which I use in the combobox ItemTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cmbTemplate" x:Name="cmbTemplate">
<WrapPanel Margin="0 0 0 0" Background="Transparent">
<Image Width="25" Height="25" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Logo}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0">
</Image>
<Viewbox Width="125" Height="50">
<ContentPresenter Name="cmbContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource btcvector}"  />
</Viewbox>
<Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,15,0" FontSize="20"/>
</WrapPanel></DataTemplate>
```

The viewbox contains a contentpresenter which contains the svg image. The svg images are declared in my app.xaml file in the application resources section. Ideally I want to fill an object which contains the listitems e.g. image(svg resource) - description. I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need a representative class for each item, which has to inherit from DependencyObject for this trick to work. Then you add your Image and Description properties as DependencyProperties to that class. For Example

```
public class Item : DependencyObject {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(SVGWhateverType), typeof(Item),new PropertyMetadata(default(SVGWhateverType)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Item),new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public SVGWhateverType Image {
      get { return (SVGWhateverType)this.GetValue(ImageProperty); }
      set { this.SetValue(ImageProperty, value); } 
    }

    public string Name {
      get { return (string)this.GetValue(NameProperty); }
      set { this.SetValue(NameProperty, value); } 
    }
}
```

You then create a List of those Objects and assign them to the ItemsSource-Property as you probably did before somehow.

Now you only need two further steps:

1. Change your template: Currently you are referencing a dynamic resource. Change that to reference the Image-Property of the newly created object.
2. Bind the Image to the correct dynamic resource. Doing that is rather simple if you know how to do it. When you populate your individual items, you just call
   `item.Image = FindResource("ResourceNameHere");`
   and you're done.

If you really want to bind the images dynamically, e.g. for exchanging them at runtime by switching resource dictionaries, this whole thing gets a lot harder to pull off.

Comment: You Sir have saved me allot of time! Thanks!